# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input javascript in visual studio code editor. it works fine in sublime text

Tags: javascript

When i run this code in visual studio in shows me error..but i run this code in other code editor it is working fine.

```
// code....
var account = {
  name: "john",
  income: 0,
  expense: 0
};

//add income
var addIncome = function(myAccount, inc = 34) {
  myAccount.income += inc;
  return myAccount.income;
};

var addInc = addIncome(account);
console.log(addInc);    
var addExpense = function(myAccount, exp = 0) {
  myAccount.expense += exp;
  return myAccount.expense;
};

var addExp = addExpense(account, 1000);
console.log(addExp);
var getAccountSummary = function(myAccount) {
    console.log(`in my account total income is: ${myAccount.income} and my expense:${myAccount.expense}');
};
getAccountSummary(account);
console.log(account);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using mismatched quotes on this line:

```js
console.log(`in my account total income is: ${myAccount.income} and my expense:${myAccount.expense}');
```

Note that you start the string with a backtick, but end with a single quote. Try replacing the single quote with a backtick:

```js
console.log(`in my account total income is: ${myAccount.income} and my expense:${myAccount.expense}`);
```